# How to deal with onChange in ReactQuill Editor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am using ReactQuill component in my react project . In my page i have multiple component like (TextBox/InputNumber Box/DropDown) so from each component i am calling a event

```
<TextField  error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.targetDateValid} name="targetDate" onChange={this.handleChange} type="date"  label="Target date" variant="outlined"  />
```

So this component also calling `handleChange` event and this `onChange` will pass `event` and from event we can get the `value`

```
 handleChange(event) {
        console.log('Value', event.target.value);
}
```

So i want to call same `handelChange` event but

> The onChange for the TextField input receives an event containing name and
> value.On the other hand the onChange for the Quill component receives
> the actual content.

SO i tried to wrote a separate event method

```
 handleChangeEditor(editor) {
        console.log('background', editor);
        let _postForm = this.state.postForm;

        _postForm.notesValid = true;
        _postForm.notes = editor;

        if (editor.length < 30) { _postForm.notesValid = false; }

        

        this.setState({ ...this.state, postForm: _postForm });
    };
```

But after doing this ,this line of code have some issue
`this.setState({ ...this.state, postForm: _postForm });`  if i will add this then ReactQuill Editor's text area wont show anything whatever i am writing.

and ReactQuill COmponent be like

```
 <ReactQuill theme="snow" formats={this.formats} value={this.state.text || ''} modules={this.modules} placeholder="Write Something about your view" id="notesTextArea" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.notesValid} onChange={this.handleChangeEditor} name="notesTextArea" />
```

Answer (score 3):

So after some few changes i am able to fix the issue

First change in component ,in `value` section used `this.state.postForm.notes`

```
<ReactQuill theme="snow" formats={this.formats} value={this.state.postForm.notes || ''} modules={this.modules} placeholder="Write Something about your view" id="notesTextArea" error={this.state.postForm.isValidationActive && !this.state.postForm.notesValid} onChange={this.handleChangeEditor} name="notesTextArea" />
```

Second change in Handler Method

```
 handleChangeEditor(editor) {
        console.log('background', editor);
        let _postForm = this.state.postForm;

        _postForm.notesValid = true;
        _postForm.notes = editor;

        if (editor.length < 30) { _postForm.notesValid = false; }



        this.setState({ ...this.state, postForm: _postForm });
    };
```